# Restricting the addin to the stereotype

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I have build a MDG Toolbox. I have a windows form which is created using C#.
Now We want to enable i.e to open the windows form only when the particular stereotype is selected in the project browser of EA.

Comment: Yes and? You'll have to tell us what you tried and where you hit a problem.  You can't expect the SO users to do the work for you. (unless you pay them ofcourse ;))

Answer (score 0):

When the context item (selection) is changed, EA fires an event to all Add-Ins. In order to respond, write a handler called `EA_OnContextItemChanged()` in your Add-In main class.